# Difference between LCD Displays

Tags: hardware, display, peripherals

I was using a Hitachi HD44780 display hooked up to GPIO pins. Sadly, it got damaged and, in a rush, I had to get a different one. It is a ADM1602U serial enabled display. However I don't plan to use the serial function of it. The pin out diagram is given in the link below

http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/LCD/Monochrome/ADM1602U_2.pdf

I was wondering if anyone could tell me the difference between the pins of the generic HD44780 display (tutorial I was using for the old display : http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/07/16x2-lcd-module-control-using-python/) and this new display.

It appears the only real difference is the PGD, PGC, and PGM pins which I am not sure what to connect it to.

Comment: The HD44780 according to Wikipedia appears to use a parallel interface while the ADM1602U uses a serial UART interface.  The Pi does have a serial port, but by default Raspbian uses it for the console.

Comment: Is there anyway to use the JP1 and JP2 pins on the ADM1602U to make it into a parallel interface?

Comment: Looks like you can just use the 10 pin header. To me it looks like its is just a normal HD44780 display, but it has a PIC chip on the board that does the serial, to "parallel" conversion. The PGD, PGC, and PGM are PIC programming pins. So just ignore the 6-pin one.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I thought that might be it, but I wasn't sure.